# Convert JSON to Pattern on Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, json, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I want to use JSON to compare String. I have website in different language so i take string from JSON file.
String could be:

```
Gender: Male
```

or

```
Gender: Female
```

In Selenium IDE i write:

```
try
{
    assertTrue(Pattern.compile("Gender: *(Male|Female)").matcher(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[3]")).getText()).find());
}
catch (Error e)
{
    verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
}
```

and now I want to convert this to Java using JSON and SeleniumWebDriver

```
protected static void feedbacksCheck(WebDriver driver, JSONObject pageLanguage) throws JSONException
{
    assertEquals(true, Pattern.compile(pageLanguage.get("GENDER") + ": " + "*(" + pageLanguage.get("MALE") + "|" + pageLanguage.get("FEMALE") + ")")
                    .matcher(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/span")).getText()).find());
}
```

I don't know if this work ok because on compare result I could see true or false. How to change this code to see on compare result all string from website?